# Android Lock-task mode and sounds

Tags: android, kiosk-mode

I am trying to understand the Android Lock-task mode.
My requirement is to run an application in which the user does not get disrupted by messages and sounds of other apps (like incoming calls).
I run my app in Lock-task mode, which looks to solve a big deal of my use case. But incoming call sounds seem not to be blocked in lock-task mode.
Can this be done with lock task mode or do I need another solution for that ?

I tried AudioManager.getFocus(AUDIO_GAIN) when starting my app on top of activating lock task mode but this is not a solution. Incoming calls keep making sounds.